# Request.user on Django Model forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ledger account table that consist of ledger accounts of all the companies. The user in logged into a specific company and hen he selects an account to use on a form only the accounts that company must be available for the user. for this purpose I use the request.user to determine the user. I however get an error "request does not exist". I understand why it is not available on the forms.py as there is no request executed. Is there a way that I can make request.user available of the form.

Models.py

```
class tledger_account(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    gl_category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=category_choices, verbose_name='category', db_index=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default=None)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(tcompany, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
```

forms.py

```
class SelectAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_from = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=year_range))
    date_to = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=year_range))
    select_account = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=tledger_account.objects.filter(
        company = request.user.current_company))

    class Meta:
        model = ttemp_selection
        fields = ['select_account', 'date_from', 'date_to']
```

Comment: you going form `SelectAccountForm` from django admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use request.user you are using the fields of the user model so it is not necessary to have them in the form, for that you need to have a forensic relationship with the user model:

```
class tledger_account(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    gl_category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=category_choices, verbose_name='category', db_index=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, default=None)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(tcompany, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_index=True)
```

and the view:

```
def tledger_account_view(request):
    template_name = 'your template'
    user = request.user
    tledger_account = tledger_account.objects.get(user=user)

    return render(request, template_name, {
        'tledger_account': tledger_account,
    })
```

more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hoever can't see that this will work. The ledger account is not linked to a specific user but to the company. There could be several users linked to the company that need access to the same ledger accounts. The company is linked to the users and I need to derive the company from the current user. the ledger account is a foreign key on other models and it is on these models that the ledger account must be filtered based on the request.user.company (company is a field on the user model)

Comment: then ask your question more understandable, if you do not enter the complete models it is impossible to give a correct help

Comment: I found the solution. I used class-based views to send the request.user to the form. This reference explains how to do it. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/django-how-to-pass-the-user-object-into-form-classes-ee322f02948c

Comment: It's a good post, it helped me, I made a different solution, but the one in the post is cleaner, so I changed it, thanks